# How to use .html() to change content later in document

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to rewrite the html in 2 `<p>` tags when I check a checkbox. Note: the `<div class="summary">` container repeats many times based on output from a DB.

* HTML ***

```
<div class="summary">
    <div>Data 1</div>
    <div>Data 2</div>
    <div class="col_5"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
</div>
<div class="details">
    <p>label:</p><p>info</p>
    <p>label 2:</p><p>more info</p>
    <p class="jQuery1">another label to be changed:</p><p class="jQuery2">final info to be changed</p>
</div>
```

* JavaScript (everything works except comments 1 & 2) ***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(event) {
        $(this).closest('div.col_5').html('Yes');
        $('div.details').next('p.jQuery1').html('Changed 1'); // c1 -- this does not work
        $('div.details').next('p.jQuery2').html('Changed 2'); // c2 -- this does not work
    });
    $('.summary').click(function(e){
        if ($("input:checked").length == 0) {
            $(this).next('.details').slideToggle('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.next()` method returns the next *sibling* of the element you call it on, but you are trying to find *children* of the element you call it on so you should use `.children()` (to retrieve only direct children) or `.find()` (to get descendants including children, grandchildren, etc.).

Try the following:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(event) {
    var $div = $(this).closest('div.col_5'),
        $nextDiv = $div.closest('div.summary').next('div.details');
    $div.html('Yes');
    $nextDiv.find('p.jQuery1').html('Changed 1');
    $nextDiv.find('p.jQuery2').html('Changed 2');
});
```

The reason I'm keeping a reference (`$div`) to the clicked checkbox's parent div is because you need it to find the div afterwards and you won't be able to use `this` after you've overwritten the div's html with the string 'Yes' since that deletes the element that `this` refers to.

Comment: My apologies, see my edit. My original answer didn't traverse up from `.col_5` to `.summary` before calling `.next()`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `next()` use `find()` or `children()`:

```
$('div.details').find('p.jQuery1').html('Changed 1');
```

Comment: that worked except it changed every p.jQuery* -- not just the "next" one. I need to only change the next instance. I'll try children() and see if that works better.

Comment: children() did the same thing find() did -- it changed everyone instance.

Answer (score 0):

use find instead of next because you are trying to look a children inside the div with class details

```
 $('div.details').find('p.jQuery1').html('Changed 1');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HTaKV/2/

and in the second binding you are doing slideToggle so the changed the content is getting hided. So i commented that line to get the visibility of change